# How to filter millions of documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, performance, large-data

I'm trying to filter through millions of documents. Each document is about 7kB in size.
For the moment, I'm filtering on a maximum of 8 (defined) fields, but more will be added later.

Filters can be anything, like :

- "field": "value"
- "field: {"$gte": value}
- "field": {"$regex": "regexp"}
- "field": {"$in": [...]}
- etc...

I want it to be quick. So I've created indexes.
But I don't know if I need to create every possible index.
Example:
For fields a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h :

- should I create a single compound index with all these fields ?
- or create every combinaison of indexes :

  - a
  - a,b
  - [...]
  - b,e,g,h
  - etc...

The problem with doing this is that you're limited to 64 indexes.

But even with the right indexes, the search takes a long time sometimes.

I have also a wildcard index on an object. I tried to create a compound index with this wildcard index but it is never used. So the query is pretty slow when I’m searching on my normal filters + the filter that has the wildcard index.

Is there a solution for having a higher number of filterable fields without having index or performance problems?
Maybe create a smaller collection with all these filters ? Create a collection for every filter and request each collection and cross the results to find the corrects results ?
I don’t know..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are among the most important tools to speed up queries; however, indexes should be able to be kept in RAM and thus only the required indexes should be created. This also depends on the data model that you are using. Creating many indexes in lots of variations puts a lot of load on the RAM of the cluster, even if you manage to keep it under the maximum of 64 indexes.

In order to reduce the amount of indexes needed, have a look at the [attribute pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern). This pattern proposes to move attributes from dedicated fields to attribute arrays, e.g. (sample taken from the blog post)

The following schema

```
{
  // ...
  "releasedate_en": ISODate("2024-01-20T00:0000Z"),
  "releasedate_de": ISODate("2024-01-22T00:0000Z"),
  // ... 
 }
```

is restructured like this:

```
{
  // ...
  "releases": [
    { "location": "en", "date": ISODate("2024-01-20T00:0000Z") },
    { "location": "de", "date": ISODate("2024-01-22T00:0000Z") },
  ]
  // ... 
 }
```

Instead of creating dedicated indexes for all the attributes, you can create a single index that covers the attribute name and value, e.g.

```
{ "releases.location": 1, "releases.date": 1}
```

In the sample, the attributes have a very homogenous structure, but from a technical point of view you can also group attributes with different value types in the array.

Using this pattern you can reduce the amount of indexes dramatically and you do not have to depict all the combinations of the fields.

Comment: Thanks

But I don't see how I can apply that to my collection. My fields are like : 
- name
- postal code
- size
- capital amount
- creation date
-...

But in any case, even if I put all these fields in an object array, I'll have to create a compound index with all the fields: it doesn't change the index I've already created. And the problem of search performance remains the same if I don't use all the fields in my search.

Unless I'm mistaken? But if I have 8 fields on which I want to filter but my query only has 2, it won't use the index, or it will use it but it won't be fast.

Comment: If you move all the attributes to the array as the pattern proposes, you only need a compound index that contains the key- and the value-field of the array. There is no need for a compound index for all the single fields. I agree that this works best if you have similar attributes, but maybe a combination of the approaches is possible (keep important fields, e.g. name on the doc, move additional attributes to an array).

Comment: Okay, I see.
For example, I could do this: 
```[
{ "type": "zipCode", "value": "75000"},
{ "type": "creationDate", "value": "2023-05-10"},
[...]
]```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea - technically it is also possible to use matching data types for value, e.g. date or integer, ... if using `$elemMatch`, e.g. `attributes: { $elemMatch: { type: "zipCode", value: "75000" } } to query for the attributes, the index is also used as expected. Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need indexes on low-cardinality field. Create the indexes only on selective fields. For example an index on field `gender` which contain only [`male`, `female`, `others`] would be useless in most cases.

Note, normal indexes are not used in every case for `$regex`, see [Index Use](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But none of my fields have low-cardinality

Comment: Hard to believe - "low cardinality" does not mean "only 3 values". Compare in relation to total number of documents. Create index on most commonly used fields, I don't think they will be really evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

With you question:`create every combinaison of indexes`. The answer is `no`. The collection with many index make `reduced write performance and longer index builds` and `insufficient RAM`. In addition, It can cause query to astray by an index, that is not optimal because there are too many indexes.

`should I create a single compound index with all these fields ?`. The answer also is `no`. See the [post](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) to create some index that cover some case query and sort that you need. If you have many index, You can use `hint` to figure out which option is the most suitable